# Cursor position jumps when typing fast in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have UITextView in app, Its used like text editor app.
When typing long text and typing fast textview cursor position behave weird, its jumping like typewriter. You can find GIF from below link.

On typing every word API is calling to check word correction, Anybody facing same issue ?

https://gph.is/2CF0AzQ

Comment: Having API calls in textView delegates to check text is a very bad idea. It's probably the API taking time to respond that is causing the issue.

Comment: I have commented API calls for testing purpose, its still behaving same

Comment: Then you need to show your code.

Comment: Maybe set selection at the end of the text, when you typing?

Comment: yeah, show what you have done